# Trouble indexing dataframe in R

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to construct a linear model using using forward step selection. The issue is that once i've extracted the coefficients im not sure how to index the dataframe to refer to all rows but only those columns with the coefficients i found by using forward step selection. In the code below out of 25 predictors, i want to select 10 using forward step

About the data set, column 1 is the response, and the rest of the columns are labelled x1,x2,...,x25, with the corrosponding values beneath them, i also have 50 observations, so dim(train_data) = 50,26. I was trying to somehow use names(t) and select the columns like that but i get errors.

```
regfit.forward = regsubsets(y~.,data = train_data,method='forward',nvmax = 25)
s <-summary(regfit.forward)
t <- coef(regfit.forward,10)

#not sure how to select only columns with the coefficients selected by t
train_data[,t] #doesnt work
train_data[,names(t)] #doesnt work :

#both errors respectively from train_data attempts:
#Error in .subset(x, j) : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
#Error in `[.data.frame`(train_data, , names(t)) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

Any help appreciated, thank you.

Comment: fit <- leaps::regsubsets(medv ~ ., data = MASS::Boston, method = "forward", nvmax = 5); 
df <- MASS::Boston[, c("medv", names(coef(fit, 3))[-1])]

Comment: @Zen thank you, there was a intercept term i wasnt getting rid of which the [-1] part took it out and it works now.